# how can I run docker containers in detached mode within a committed image

Tags: docker

I have pulled an image called **php:5.6-apache**, run it, touch a file in /var/www/html, then commit it.

Then I try to run the new image in detached mode:

```
# docker run --name test -d staraple/php:v1
```

But the container exited immediately after started.

```
IMAGE                COMMAND              CREATED                STATUS       
staraple/php:v2  "apache2 -DFOREGROUN   4 seconds ago       Exited (0) 3 seconds ago
```

Fisrt I though the new image lost the **CMD** after a  **commit** action.

Refer to https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/4000 , CMD will reserved after commit;

My problem is why my container could not run in detached mode when I got a CMD. **php.5.6-apache** is official, and I just touch a blank file in it.

ps:
    When I check json for images in /var/lib/docker/graph, I found my new image has a different Cmd config from the original one:

```
 old:  "Cmd":["/bin/sh","-c","#(nop) CMD [apache2 -DFOREGROUND]"]
 new:  "Cmd":["apache2","-DFOREGROUND"]
```

`docker logs`   show message: `https (pid 1) already running` .

Comment: What does `docker logs` return for that container?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco 
Here is the log:
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.31. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message.         httpd (pid 1) already running

Answer (score 1):

I received an answer form forums.docker.com:

https://forums.docker.com/t/how-can-i-run-docker-containers-in-detached-mode-within-a-committed-image/255

My commited image still have the apache pid on the FS which introduce the log "https (pid 1) already running". I should make sure to shut down the apache in my initial run cleanly.

In my case, it's necessary to stop the container before commit it.